# How to define a special escape sequence for a listings block which bold italicizes the text it surrounds?

Tags: listings

I currently have a listings set up which uses `!>` and `<!` as an escape sequence. The main purpose I use this for is to make the text in a listings stand out by bold-italicizing them when writing placeholders for ideas in code. One example is...

```
\begin{lstlistings}[lisp]
if (not <boolean condition>)
          (!>\textit{\bfseries form when not condition}<!)
\end{lstlistings}
```

I'd like to just make it so that surrounding the text by `!>` and `<!` automatically bold, italicizes the text, and make it part of the default font of the document, so that writing...

```
\begin{lstlistings}[lisp]
if (not <boolean condition>)
          (!>form when not condition<!))
\end{lstlistings}
```

gives me...

[image: emphasize text in listings]

Is this possible?